# Kanji that don't use their specified readings

Tags: kanji, readings, multiple-readings

Hello I'm trying to understand something about kanji readings.
As far as I understand each Kanji character has multiple readings and each of these readings can be used alone or in conjunction with different kanji.

My question is, how is it that sometimes I see words that do not use any specified reading of the kanji, for example:

日 
can be read as ひ, -び, -か，ニチ, ジツ

but in the word いっぴ (一日)
it is used as ぴ

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/13556/7810

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, be aware that 一日 is usually read *ichinichi*, to count one day, or *tsuitachi*, when it refers to the first day of a month (as in "April the 1st").  But the phenomenon you spotted in *ippi* also happens to other words, so let's talk about that.

The simple explanation of *ippi* is that, when you join a ち (like いち) to ひ, the sequence ち-ひ usually becomes っぴ.  So you see, the 日 is using its common ひ reading, after all.  It's just that ぴ is considered to be a transformation of ひ (in this case, triggered by ち).  More details follow.

The change from ひ to ぴ is an example of a *sound change* or *euphony* (Japanese: 音便{おんびん}).  There are two important types of sound change which may happen when linking words into a compound:

**Sequential voicing** (連濁{れんだく}): The first kana character of the *second* word may get a *dakuten* ゛ mark.  For example, 棚 たな → 本棚 ほん**だ**な. (In linguistics terms, the second word becomes [voiced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_(phonetics)), except if it begins with an /h/, which becomes /b/.  That's because /h/ was /p/ in Old Japanese, and a voiced /p/ is a /b/.)

If the *kana* cannot normally be written with a *dakuten* ゛, then no sound change happens. Even if it can, sometimes it doesn't change.  It's a bit hard to predict when will *rendaku* occur ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendaku)).  Just be aware that it does happen, and with time you'll get a feel for it.

**Gemination** (促音便{そくおんびん}): When two words are linked, the first consonant of the *second* word may become doubled (*gemini* is Latin for "twins").  The doubled or "long" consonants are easier to see in rōmaji:

- 発 *hatsu* + 達 *tatsu* → *ha**tt**atsu*
- 一 *ichi* + 個 *ko* → *i**kk**o*
- 真 *ma* + 白 *shiro* = *ma**ss**hiro*

Gemination is often triggered by the first word ending with a つ or ち. In this case, the trailing つ or ち will become a "small *tsu*" (that is, the syllable will disappear, being subsumed into the new geminated consonant):

- 発 はつ + 達 たつ → 発達 は**っ**たつ
- 一 いち + 個 こ → 一個 い**っ**こ

A sequence of /k/ sounds also gets geminated, with one /k/-kana becoming a small *tsu*:

- 悪 あく + 化 か → 悪化 あっか

Sometimes no character becomes a small *tsu*; the small *tsu* seemingly pops out of nowhere:

- 真 ま + 白 しろ → 真っ白 まっしろ

Finally, /h/-sounds (は,ひ,ふ,へ,ほ) are special.  Whenever a /h/-sound gets geminated, it becomes a /pp/ sound; that is, the はひふへほ kana get a *handakuten* ゜ mark, becoming ぱぴぷぺぽ.  (Again, this is because /h/ used to be /p/ in Old Japanese).  This is what happened to 一日 as いっぴ, and it happens often for counters starting with 一 いち:

- 一発 いっぱつ
- 一匹 いっぴき
- 一夫 いっぷ
- 一片 いっぺん
- 一本 いっぽん

Comment: Although this is implied, I think it would be helpful to state specifically in response to the question that the reason why, for example, ぴ is not a "specified reading" of 日 is because of this phenomenon. The ぴ in this case is actually a ひ, etc.

Comment: @Ciaran: you're right; I added the clarification.

Comment: Nice answer. Do you (or anyone) know how to determine whether 一 as いっ is more likely to be イツ or イチ? (Here いっぴ could be イツ＋ひ or イチ＋ひ, right?)

Comment: @Earthliŋ Right. I don't think there's a way to determine which is more likely by the phonology itself. Speakers will infer that by their lexicon database – e.g. 個{こ} (small object counter) will occur after いち (“one”), not after いつ (“when”), so いっこ (in a context where 一個 makes sense) must surely come from いち＋こ.  Likewise, ねっけつ must come from ねつ＋けつ for the simple reason that the only compound that fits is 熱血 – there's not even a word like ＊ねち to compete with it. (One reason is that many *on-yomi* words ending in つ or ち originally ended in /-t/, like *net-*; the vowel was a latter addition).

Comment: (And いっぴ won't fit for いつ – if you tried to use いつ here, you'd need a の, resulting in いつの日{ひ}.)

Comment: I was talking about イツ as the *kan on* reading of 一 (as in 唯一 【ゆいいつ】), not about いつ as in 何時.

Comment: Oh, I see! Well, *kan'on* comes from Chang'an Late Middle Chinese, and *go'on* from Late Old Chinese; but the thing is, 一 “one” was ＊ʔit- in both, and entered Japanese as *it-* – the form it had in the Jesuit materials, ca. 16 century (cf. Frellesvig, section 11.4). I think the *ichi/itsu* pair doesn't come from real, distinct *kan/go'on* etymons, but this distinction is a late back-formation from *it-* – what Miller once called the "linguistic ghosts" of Japanese lexicography.  Therefore, *ippi* actually comes from neither /itu/ nor /iti/, but from their ancestor and Old/Middle J form /it-/.

Comment: (Continued) There's several pieces of evidence for the fact that premodern *on'yomi* ended with a *-t*; the most decisive being the Jesuit vocabularies, which describe the phonology of Middle Japanese pretty clearly. It has also been shown that words ending in *-t* were written in Middle Japanese with particular *hentaigana* characters, to distinguish them from actually pronounced ち and つ. Finally, the Sinologists assure us that the original Old/Middle Chinese forms ended in a /t/ – among other evidence, 一 is currently *chit* or *it* in Taiwanese, *jat* in Cantonese and *nhất* in Vietnamese.

Comment: As for 真っ白, some claim that it derives from prefix "ma" with  reduplicated adjectives, which is shared with Filipino or Melanesian languages. This feature is well reserved in "ma aka aka" → まっかっか.