# Is いっしゅるい the correct reading of 1種類?

Tags: readings, counters

> 「いろいろやると大変【たいへん】になるから」と、メニューはカレーライス[1種類]【いっしゅるい】のみ
> *He opened a small curry shop with only one type of curry rice on the menu, saying, "If I do too many things, it will be too much work."*

Is いっしゅるい the correct reading of 1種類? Or possibly ひと or いち?

I found it in a sentence here:

https://www.asahi.com/articles/ASPDH6RQ9PCMONFB019.html?iref=comtop_Topic_01

Comment: Related: [Are there rules of thumb for counter sound changes?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13548/43676)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, いっしゅるい is a correct and more common reading although ひとしゅるい is possible.

いっしゅるい is [促音便](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%9F%B3%E4%BE%BF#%E4%BF%83%E9%9F%B3%E4%BE%BF) of いちしゅるい. It may be not impossible to pronounce it as いちしゅるい if the speaker wants to put an emphasis, saying it slowly, but it should be rare.